# JQuery dynamic option check with post data

Tags: jquery, post, dialog

I have a problem and I cannot for the life of me figure what the hell I've done wrong here.  I know it's an issue somewhere but all the possible solutions I've tried don't work.  Here goes!

I'm using FullCalendar as a booking system, which has an external database check to see whether a room is booked for the time being requested in FullCalendar. The check works perfectly (returns a zero for not booked or a higher figure if something is booked during the period).  But I've put code in to prevent you from being able to book a slot if a room is already taken.  Then you click cancel and select another date/time range from FullCalendar, which then performs another check.  Problem is, the check also includes the previous check (returning 1 if it's on a booked slot) and also checking the new slot, firing off two post queries (if the first slot I attempt to book is already taken, this returns a 1, then the second attempt without refreshing returns a 1 and then a 0 as two separate post queries) - this happens again and again, increasing by 1 post query each time.  How can I stop it from posting more than once?  I hope this makes some sense!

Here is the code performing the check from a dynamically created dialog.

```
$('#msgBox').on('change','#room',function() {
    room = $( "#room option:selected" ).text();
    host = $( "#host" ).val();
    console.log(room)
    if (room == "Boardroom") {
        $('#coffee').show()
    } else {
        $('#coffee').hide()
    }
    $.post('checkroom.asp',{
        name : host,
        room : room, 
        start : moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), 
        end :  moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        },
        function(data){
            if(data > 0){
                if (Admin) {
                    $(":button:contains('Ok')").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    $(":button:contains('OK + Book Room')").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    $('#msgBox3').html('The room you have selected is showing as booked for these times, but you are admin and can override this.')
                } else {
                    $(":button:contains('Ok')").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    $(":button:contains('OK + Book Room')").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    $('#msgBox3').html('The room you have selected is showing as booked for these times, please select an alternative room.')
                }                           
                $('#msgBox3').dialog('option','title','Unable to proceed')
                $('#msgBox3').dialog('option','buttons',[{text: "Ok", click: function(){$('#msgBox3').dialog('close')}}])
                $('#msgBox3').dialog('open')

            } else {
                $(":button:contains('Ok')").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                $(":button:contains('OK + Book Room')").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            }
        }

    )               
});
```

Comment: The described behaviour makes it look like you're binding the `.on("change")` handler more than once. The code posted is okay, but make sure you're not doing this elsewhere, and make sure any external plugins (like FullCalendar) are also not doing it without telling you. If this is not the problem, could you make a MCVE?

Comment: I have a feeling I have so many different variables I can't put together a MCVE but I'll try my best to sort something!  It does appear that it is binding more than once, I will try moving the code around and outside of the actual code it's in, to be honest that may just solve it, I'll try that and report back.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievably, with a fresh pair on Monday morning eyes, I've solved this with one character.  And that character happens to be an "e".

With @blgt saying it's binding the handler more than once, I just googled a way of binding it just once and the `.one` event handler fitted the bill so changing the `.on` to `.one` now means it only fires once!

It was a gentle push in the right direction and I have some small sense of glee for having fixed it myself for a change :)